# STM32F4 HAL - PWM Phase shifting channels on the same timer

Tags: pwm, stm32, timer, stm32f4

I've configured my STM32F407VG (STM32F4Discovery) TIM4 timer using the following code:

```
void TIM4_Init(void)
{
    // Configure TIM4 for PWM
    hTim4.Instance = TIM4;
    hTim4.Init.Prescaler= 42000 - 1; // (84MHz / 42000 = 2KHz)
    hTim4.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
    hTim4.Init.Period = 2000 - 1; // Period = 2000 -> 1 second
    hTim4.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
    HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&hTim4);

    // Configure channels 1-4 for TIM4,
    // each channel is mapped to a GPIO pin
    TIM_OC_InitTypeDef oc_config;
    oc_config.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
    oc_config.Pulse = 1000;
    oc_config.OCNIdleState = TIM_OCNIDLESTATE_RESET;
    oc_config.OCIdleState = TIM_OCIDLESTATE_RESET;
    oc_config.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;

    HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&hTim4, &oc_config, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
    HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&hTim4, &oc_config, TIM_CHANNEL_3);

    // Flip the OC polarity for channels 2 and 4
    oc_config.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_LOW;
    HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&hTim4, &oc_config, TIM_CHANNEL_2);
    HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&hTim4, &oc_config, TIM_CHANNEL_4);

    // I want to shift channel 1-4 90 degrees apart...
    HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&hTim4, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
    HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&hTim4, TIM_CHANNEL_2);
    HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&hTim4, TIM_CHANNEL_3);
    HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&hTim4, TIM_CHANNEL_4);
}
```

Each channel is mapped to a GPIO pin, with the intention of driving a stepper motor.

I would like to generate a signal, with a duty cycle of 25% each, where the phases have been shifted 90 degrees apart.

**How do I go about shifting the phases on the 4 channels?**

Should I setup another timer, and use it as an interrupt upon which I can call HAL_TIM_PWM_Start() for each channel at the appropriate timing?

Comment: It is feasible to get two phases from a timer, but IIRC, 4 will be tricky. Why do you want to use only one timer (STM32F4's have quite a lot)? Are you willing to take interrupts for some of the channels? Exactly which STM32F4 are you using?

Comment: I'm using a STM32F407VG, on the STM32F4 Discovery board.

Comment: My understanding is that three-phase PWM is possible with "advanced timers", TIM1 and TIM8, but I don't thing 4-phase is with simple PWM use

Comment: Spent last night looking deeper into this, and it doesn't seem phase shifting on all 4 channels on a single timer is possible at all. Except for flipping the OC polarity, there's nothing more to be done, so this seems to be a dead end.